# Reading XML data into lazarus

Tags: xml, freepascal, lazarus

I need to read XML data into lazarus, in order to present this data as gui elements. for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<guiform>
  <category name="aaa">
    <item a="abc" b="12" c="1e-10" d="blah blah blah" />
    <item a="asa" b="13" c="0" d="" />
    <item a="juy" b="43" c="0" d="dh dh dh" />
  </category>
  <category name="bbb">
    <item a="hgf" b="87" c="1.5" d="a b d c" />
    <item a="rtg" b="42" c="0" d="ty th hgf" />
  </category>
</guiform>
```

Every category will become a tab on a form, and the items will become radio buttons. What is the best way of doing this? RTTI? Or maybe read & parse the file?
And how to populate the GUI elements? (example would be great as I am a beginner..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the XML using fcl-xml, and then write code to instantiate the relevant components.

Comment: I will use the examples that come with lazarus, see if I can make something out of it.

Answer (score 1):

TXMLPropStorage does this for you already.